# Bootstrap tooltip focus not working in safari and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, focus, tooltip

I am working on a project to add social sharing buttons inside a tooltip when a certain button is clicked.  I am using the bootstrap tooltip and have setup the tooltip trigger to be "focus".  This way if the user doesn't want to select any social sharing buttons they can click anywhere and the tooltip will close.  This is working great in Chrome!  That is the only browser it works in however.  I have gotten Firefox (had to switch the trigger to click instead of focus and add some JS) to work with a little fix but I still can't get Safari to work.  Right now in safari I can click on the button to get the tooltip to show but when I click elsewhere it doesn't disappear.  So my question is; does anyone know how to fix these issues across browsers so that focus will work?  Specifically onblur for safari?

## Code w/Firefox Fix

### Javascript

```
    :javascript
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();          
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').blur(function(e){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide')
        })
      });
```

### HAML

```
   %div= link_to "Something", post_up_vote_path(post), 
   remote: true, class: 'something btn btn-sm btn-success', 
   :data => {toggle: 'tooltip', placement: 'bottom', 
   trigger: "click", html: 'true'}, 
   :title => "<h5>Share</h5> #{render 'votes/social', :post => post}"
```